# Wordpress site not displaying properly on an iPad

Tags: wordpress, ipad

I am using a modified version of the Quintus Theme in a self-hosted WordPress site.  The site appears and works great on all browsers that I have tested, a windows tablet, and a windows phone. When I view the site on an iPad running the latest iOS version, the site is being squished to what I would assume is between 700-800px wide... all except for my custom header and slider. The blog title, menu and everything contained within the #page is not showing full width. I have beat my head against a wall trying to locate this needle in the haystack to find what could be causing this to display short of the width.  I even tried some iPad emulators, however all those display the site perfectly.  The actual iPad is not. I am not sure how to inspect the elements on an iPad since there are not any options on an iPad broswer to do so. Can someone please help me?

Blog... http://blog.modafabrics.com

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in Safari?

Comment: No... Safari for Windows OS displays great. So far I have only had the problem on Safari and Mercury browsers on the iPad.

Comment: Issue Resolved... looked to be a margin and padding issue. I didn't have margins specified on certain elements in the code and apparently the iPad doesn't like that. Added a margin of 0 to the main containers and all is working great now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the chrome emulator, i can't see any responsive `CSS` being used.

Your big slider area in the middle is set to a width of 1000px, whereas a iPad's resolution is only around 1024 x 768px. When in portrait you will be missing almost a quarter of the screen size.

The best way around it would be to start using percentages once you hit 1024px and to start making it responsive so it works on all devices, mobiles included.

Have a read on the MDN about media queries which are what are used in responsive `CSS`.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

## EDIT

Ill see if i can get you started on making things a bit better.

These are all changes needed within your css which need to be applied within the media query for tablets

```
#page {
    overflow-x: hidden; // stops the page being slid to right
}

#primary {
   float: none; // removes the float style from the element (things can go above/under it otherwise)
}

#content {
    margin: 0; // makes it full width
}
```

You will then need to decide what your going to do with the sidebar e.g. hide it or drop it below the content.

That should get you started on it. The best way to continue would be to use the chrome inspect element tool, you can then dig into each layer of the template and see why different things aren't re-sizing.

Comment: That is interesting... because I do actually have a responsive structure in the theme CSS. The page maximum width is set to 1100 px while the slider is set to a maximum width of 1000px. The slider does not have any responsive code built into it and it is the only thing that fits on the iPad as it should in both landscape and portrait views. It shrinks nicely to fit the width of the screen size. Unfortunately, the rest of the elements on the page do not follow suite and they do have the responsiveness built in. I even tried removing the responsive code and it did not seem to matter on the iPad.

Comment: I also tested out the site with the Chrome Emulator and like I mentioned in my original post, the Emulators all appear to work great with the iPad, however when you physically get on an iPad and go to the site, the body of the page is shortened as if it is on a much smaller mobile screen, such as a phone.